Is discouraging a permissible deed (even if explicitly permitted in Quran) forbiden?
This is a question which requires some fiqh knowledge. I just want to discuss the fiqh of it, so would prefer, if personal biases are set aside in answering the question.
My question is, would it be a correct understanding, Islamically, that when the ruling of a matter is “permissible” in the shariah rather than “Mustahhab” or “Sunnah” one can weigh the pros or cons of that matter and make own personal decision on whether to practice it or not? I ask this specifically in the context of polygamy.
If one can think to potential harms polygamy might cause - such as pain to the wife/woman and possibly statistics that point to harms would it be correct to advice against polygamy weighing its pros and cons? For eg drinking energy drinks is permissible but it’s not good for you - so you may discourage it. Just like that would it be islamically fine to discourage polygamy? Would it be different in the case of polygamy because polygamy is explicitly mentioned in the Qur’an? What is in my mind as I think about this issue is verse 1 of Surah tahrim.
By the way, for the benefit of this discussion, I am referring to the opinion of those scholars who consider polygamy only permissible and not Sunnah. I understand there are other opinions but that is not what this discussion is about.
Like I said I am interested in the fiqh so I would appreciate someone wijt some knowledge of fiqh and for personal biases to be set aside.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model and not to confound us with a typical internet forum I strongly suggest you to take the [tour] and check our [help]. This is a question-and-answer site not a forum for discussions, if you want to discuss topics you should either check the web for other platforms or earn enough reputation here to be able to open chatrooms and chat with others.

I don't see anything to discuss in terms of fiqh.  Everything is very clear and obvious anyway.   However, since you are against polygamy, the advice you give to those around you should be based on advice in daily life, not on religion.  For example, which brand of vehicle should I buy, what color should I wear, etc.
However, personalized advice can be given on this matter.  Because in such a situation, the person's living conditions will be difficult, he will have to be very careful about justice, and perhaps even the possibility of violating people's rights will increase.
Additionally, since you have an opposing view on the issue, you seem to be biased and looking for excuses for deterrence.  In fact, there is nothing sad or hurtful in this situation for devout Muslims.
If all parties are true and good Muslims, polygamy will not cause any problems.  However, if even one of the parties has problematic beliefs and morals, this will negatively affect all parties.

Thank you for not answering my question. Polygamy can certainly cause harms even if all parties are good, righteous people - for eg, one wife (the 1st one for eg might get very sad and it might take a toll on her emotionally). There is nothing against Islam to acknowledge or recognise this. That’s kind of what this question was about. You might not want to admit this due to personal biases. You do seem to lack some knowledge on Islam to get this impression. Either way Islam is sensible. Thanks for your answer, anyway.

No it is not forbidden in general, like divorce is discouraged although being permitted in Quran. This is true about anything which is Makrouh, the negation of Mustahab.
Well, this does not really answer you, since you requested we consider a deed which is only permissible (Mubah), not encouraged or discouraged (any deed which is encouraged to be done, avoiding it probably could be discouraged). But notice that a deed which is called Mustahab it doesn't imply that the deed will always be Mustahab in any situation ever imaginable. For example, rciting Quran is generally encouraged, but if the holy prophet PBUHH ask a companion to come and he bring the excuse that I'm reading Quran, that excuse will not be acceptable and reciting Quran in such a situation is Haram. Anything in its place. Something encouraged is encouraged if nothing else makes it discourage or Haram, or even obligated, like when you have a Nadhr that at 4PM today you should recite a specific page of Quran and doing so will now be Wajib and not only encourage! ... Having said this, now I grab your attention to several (Shia) Ahadeeth addressing the issue of Mut'eh (tempporary marriage) which is similar to polygamy in some aspects. There in Ahadeeth you see sometimes Mut'eh is encouraged, and sometimes discouraged, it depends on the situation. Even Polygamy might be highly encouraged or even obligatory for someone, while discouraged or forbidden for someone else. Example for one who is not allowed at al to act according to polygamy is in Quran itself:

... فَانْكِحُوا مَا طَابَ لَكُمْ مِنَ النِّسَاءِ مَثْنَيٰ وَ ثُلَاثَ
وَ رُبَاعَ فَإِنْ خِفْتُمْ أَلَّا تَعْدِلُوا فَوَاحِدَةً أَوْ مَا
مَلَكَتْ أَيْمَانُكُمْ ذَلِكَ أَدْنَيٰ أَلَّا تَعُولُوا
... Marry women of your choice, Two or three or four; but if ye fear
that ye shall not be able to deal justly (with them), then only one,
or (a captive) that your right hands possess, that will be more
suitable, to prevent you from doing injustice.

so if someone is scared of becoming unjust, he should avoid something which otherwise is permissible, if not encouraged.
My suggestion is you do not (blindly) discourage what Allah has generally permit, and instead, let your advice change from case to case, depending the situation. For example, if a man wants to marry with two women, but is afraid that his first wife will get so mad that she might kill a Muslim out of hatred, and the guy says I don't care I just see myself and my desires, this will not be accepted. If someone wants to do so, should first prepare its conditions, as no one should be hurt from this decision. This might have several details to think about from case to case, but generally discouraging something which is not generally discouraged by Allah AWJ and his prophet PBUHH, is not the right path, AFAIK.

PS. The following is not directly related to the very question that OP has asked, however, maybe this will hopefully help some people in future who have similar position against polygamy. NOTE that I'm not mind-reading or judging the OP, and according to her question she seems to very well obey Allah, and wants to help people not to suffer by misunderstanding the religious rules; therefore, do not consider what follows being implied about OP.
The point is I have discussed such issues for years with a good number of both men and women -each living their own worlds and Allah is the Lord of all worlds (رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ)- in forums on internet and in real life. Through these years I've seen Muslims who are lovers of Allah but are ashamed of some minor rules in Islam. To me they seem to have not understood Islam as good as they could.
Islam is the religion of submitting to Allah, the Needless, the Kindest, the Knowing, the Wise, and the Just. He doesn't need us to obey Him, but we do need to obey His orders, more than we do need to go by the instructions of the knowledgeable men who we know are kind and have no personal interest in us following them, like how the most pious  follower of Jesus the Christ made the argument: وَ جَاءَ مِنْ أَقْصَي الْمَدِينَةِ رَجُلٌ يَسْعَيٰ قَالَ يَا قَوْمِ اتَّبِعُوا الْمُرْسَلِينَ . اتَّبِعُوا مَنْ لَا يَسْأَلُكُمْ أَجْرًا وَ هُمْ مُهْتَدُونَ. Allah, the Needless, the Kindest, the Knowing, the Wise, and the Just, has warned us not to accept a part of the religion and reject another, that would then be a new religion beside Islam: يَقُولُونَ نُؤْمِنُ بِبَعْضٍ وَ نَكْفُرُ بِبَعْضٍ وَ يُرِيدُونَ أَنْ يَتَّخِذُوا بَيْنَ ذَلِكَ سَبِيلًا ... But Allah sometimes orders as strangely as even believers may feel not flexible enough about it. As example consider that Allah is the Unique, and near Allah perhaps nothing is worse than Shirk, but then He Himself ordered His angles to prostrate for Adam PBUH, a creature! And guess what, the Satan was seemingly the only one who wanted to only prostrate for Allah when he refused to prostrate for Adam! However, Allah didn't accept it from Satan, eventough Satan believed in Him and even asked Allah to let him instead of prostrating to Adam prostrate to Allah, a prostration as long as no one else has ever prostrated to him before alike. Satan in the view of religion has bad understanding of religion, and we call them stone-minded (متحجر) or, say, خوارج, if you know them what did they did to Imam Ali PBUH, no one of them interested in Dunya, all reciting Quran days and night, but at last one of them killed Imam Ali PBUH, and he was introduced by holy prophet PBUH years before that the worst of worst people (أشقیٰ الأشقیاء). Perhaps ISIS is one good example of such stone-minded people, who think to know Islam best but indeed know almost nothing from Islam:

وَ مِنَ النَّاسِ مَنْ يَقُولُ آمَنَّا بِاللَّهِ وَ بِالْيَوْمِ
الْآخِرِ وَ مَا هُمْ بِمُؤْمِنِين
And of the people are some who say, We believe in Allah and the Last Day, but they are not believers
...
فِي قُلُوبِهِمْ مَرَضٌ فَزَادَهُمُ اللَّهُ مَرَضًا وَ لَهُمْ عَذَابٌ
أَلِيمٌ بِمَا كَانُوا يَكْذِبُونَ
In their hearts is disease, so Allah has increased their disease; and for them is a painful punishment because they [habitually] used to lie
وَ إِذَا قِيلَ لَهُمْ لَا تُفْسِدُوا فِي الْأَرْضِ قَالُوا إِنَّمَا
نَحْنُ مُصْلِحُونَ
And when it is said to them, Do not cause corruption on the earth, they say, We are but reformers.
أَلَا إِنَّهُمْ هُمُ الْمُفْسِدُونَ وَ لَكِنْ لَا يَشْعُرُونَ
Unquestionably, it is they who are the corrupters, but they perceive [it] not
وَ إِذَا قِيلَ لَهُمْ آمِنُوا كَمَا آمَنَ النَّاسُ قَالُوا أَنُؤْمِنُ
كَمَا آمَنَ السُّفَهَاءُ أَلَا إِنَّهُمْ هُمُ السُّفَهَاءُ وَ لَكِنْ
لَا يَعْلَمُونَ
And when it is said to them, 'Believe as the people have believed,' they say, 'Should we believe as the foolish have believed?' Unquestionably, it is they who are the foolish, but they know [it] not

Allah should be obeyed even if He Himself call us to prostrate for a creature, like when He ordered Jews to enter the city while prostrating to the door, and they refused like Satan refused! قُلْنَا لَهُمُ ادْخُلُوا الْبَابَ سُجَّدًا. Allah only wants us to obey Him, to submit to Him, to simply be Muslims, and no religion will be accepted by Him but Islam: ‍‍إِنَّ الدِّينَ عِنْدَ اللَّهِ الْإِسْلَامُ.
If a woman is ordered in Hadeeth to not be zealous about her husband but she find herself so much inclined to be so, she is expected to revise her attributes, and this is growing in spirit, like a child grow and deviate from some natural desires by controlling them using the intellect power. This is purification. Natural desires for many animals might appear to be right for them, but not for human that has the intellect power. Human's nature is full of imperfections:

إِنَّا عَرَضْنَا الْأَمَانَةَ عَلَي السَّمَاوَاتِ وَ الْأَرْضِ وَ
الْجِبَالِ فَأَبَيْنَ أَنْ يَحْمِلْنَهَا وَ أَشْفَقْنَ مِنْهَا وَ
حَمَلَهَا الْإِنْسَانُ إِنَّهُ كَانَ ظَلُومًا جَهُولًا
Indeed, we offered the Trust to the heavens and the earth and the mountains, and they declined to bear it and feared it; but man [undertook to] bear it. Indeed, he was unjust and ignorant.
إِنَّ الْإِنْسَانَ لِرَبِّهِ لَكَنُودٌ . ... وَ إِنَّهُ لِحُبِّ
الْخَيْرِ لَشَدِيدٌ
Truly man is, to his Lord, ungrateful ... And indeed he is, in love of wealth, intense
فَأَمَّا الْإِنْسَانُ إِذَا مَا ابْتَلَاهُ رَبُّهُ فَأَكْرَمَهُ وَ
نَعَّمَهُ فَيَقُولُ رَبِّي أَكْرَمَنِ ... وَ أَمَّا إِذَا مَا
ابْتَلَاهُ فَقَدَرَ عَلَيْهِ رِزْقَهُ فَيَقُولُ رَبِّي أَهَانَنِ ...
كَلَّا
And as for man, when his Lord tries him and [thus] is generous to him and favors him, he says My Lord has honored me ... But when He tries him and restricts his provision, he says My Lord has humiliated me. ... Nay.
etc.

That woman says no woman can control her being zealous, is like saying Allah expects from us something we cannot, and that's against Quran where Allah says لَا يُكَلِّفُ اللَّهُ نَفْسًا إِلَّا وُسْعَهَا. Instead we can accept our weakness in obeying Allah and ask Him so to help us. Being zealous in this issue is a manifestation of being arrogant, and being arrogant although being natural but is somewhat an illness in the hearth that should be cured, and its cure happens with acquiring knowledge and reminding ourselves of the truth anytime that ignorant covers us in everyday life.
Then one should also note that Allah only orders along morality:

إِنَّ اللَّهَ لَا يَأْمُرُ بِالْفَحْشَاءِ
Indeed, Allah does not order immorality

and

إِنَّ اللَّهَ يَأْمُرُ بِالْعَدْلِ وَ الْإِحْسَانِ وَ إِيتَاءِ ذِي
الْقُرْبَيٰ وَ يَنْهَيٰ عَنِ الْفَحْشَاءِ وَ الْمُنْكَرِ وَ الْبَغْيِ
يَعِظُكُمْ لَعَلَّكُمْ تَذَكَّرُونَ.
Indeed, Allah orders justice and good conduct and giving to relatives and forbids immorality and bad conduct and oppression. He admonishes you that perhaps you will be reminded

Last but not least, you perhaps know Islam also has a temporary marriage, about which again many Muslim women cannot hide their discord, but then there is a Hadeeth from Imam Ali PBUH saying if the second Caliphate had not forbidden it, no one was committing Dhina (زناء) but only the worst of the people (الأشقیاء):

عَسَيٰ أَنْ تَكْرَهُوا شَيْئًا وَ هُوَ خَيْرٌ لَكُمْ وَ عَسَيٰ أَنْ
تُحِبُّوا شَيْئًا وَ هُوَ شَرٌّ لَكُمْ وَ اللَّهُ يَعْلَمُ وَ أَنْتُمْ
لَا تَعْلَمُونَ.
perhaps you hate a thing and it is good for you; and perhaps you love a thing and it is bad for you. And Allah Knows, while you know not.

Polygamy is not obligated commonly, but introducing it like a smear on the religion is not correct. If many, or even most, women finds it not so just at least in most cases, that might be true about the cases in their minds, but might be the cases that in some of the cases in their minds the nature of women have succeeded their intellect, which is not good news at all.

Thank you your answer makes a lot of sense, especially the last part, about changing advice based on circumstance. After looking at all that I can understand, by belief is that I am tempted to discourage polygamy. We can have many discussions about the issue but I think the simplest reason which no one ever cites is this - that it can make a woman very sad. Why do something that can cause someone sadness in this way? Now don’t get me wrong I certainly think it can bring benefits in some cases. But I think the default should be to not practice it. I hope that, that is Islamically fine

@Khadija, I have seen too many women who feels the same as you, but also rarely women who don't. Beside that, although zeal is encouraged for men relative to their wives, daughters and etc., the reverse is not true and the women are discouraged for zeal relative to their husbands. So maybe men should stop polygamy in many situations nowadays, but that doesn't mean that zealous women are on the right path either and are let free to continue being zealous about their husbands.

This is like many other natural desires/attributes, people should know themselves, and control their desires and improve their attributes. Backbiting is not encouraged even if most people do and like to do.

You have met “too many women who feel the same way” as me? So, you have met a lot of women who have been concerned about the outcome of polygamy and about the impacts it might have on other women? I never really mentioned anything about zeal. “Zealous women aren’t on the right path” - I’m not sure if zeal is something you can control. What would be haram would be to transgress, wrong someone, sin in the zeal and a Muslim should maintain the best of characters. If I were married and my husband took a second wife my zeal would only make me leave, graciously and he is free to do what he wants.

@Khadija, zeal is something that can be controlled, as being zealous is perhaps a manifestation of being arrogant, and being arrogant is something that can and must be controlled. However, there is a difference between "غیرة" as in "حمیة" (used for men in such situations) and as in "حسادة" (used for women in such situations), and maybe my English phrasing is not precise, so I hope not to make misunderstanding.

@Khadija, I added so many things to my answer as post script that may not be related to you in person, but I hope will help some others with similar (though not really the same) position.

Thanks for adding your script. You do seem to have misunderstood my question and this question is not of personal matter to me. Islam is a sensible religion if polygamy causes harms which are reasonably observed then we might take measures to discourage it except in some scenarios. Some Muslim men here seem to be offended here due to their personal biases which are more important than Islam.

@Khadija, all I added was to mean even if you are right at the present that polygamy might be discouraged in many cases "except in some scenarios", but this seems not to be natural as for creation of Allah. For example, if you feel sick you might be advised not to eat some special foods, but that's not general advice if you were not sick, and even it could be encouraged if you were healthy. I hope you will think about it, otherwise rejecting any idea opposing mine is always the easy way to go.
